# Assign IP address in hex as integer VHDL

Tags: hex, vhdl, verilog, ip-address

I am  currently working on ethernet communication on an FPGA in VHDL. For that I got the code in Verilog. In Vivado I accessing the ethernet module via a VHDL testbench. The problem is, how can I assign the IP address (e.g. 0.0.169.254) as hex value to an integer in VHDL. The code in Verilog for this is: `parameter IP_DEST = 32'hA9FE_1808`.

I translated this command to VHDL as follows: `constant IP_DEST : integer := 16#A9FE_1808#;`. Vivado is giving me the error, that this value is to big for an integer (it's interpreted as 2852001800 in dec).

How can I do that in VHDL?? Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I tried the first proposal. The simulation can be started now when I assign the value as follows: `constant IP_DEST : unsigned := x"A9FE_1808"` But how can I set the number of bits (48 bit) for an unsigned type. I tried `constant IP_DEST : unsigned (47 downto 0) := x"A9FE_1808"` but this gives me sometimes the error that the number of elements is 32, expected 48

**2nd Update:** After restarting Vivado again, the size error was gone. The constant "IP_DEST" is indeed an ethernet address. The simulation is now working. Thank you all for your help!!!

Comment: Did you try `unsigned`?

Comment: Vivado tells you that the integer type it supports is 32 bits only, that is a range of about -2^31 to 2^31-1. The unsigned hexadecimal literal `16#A9FE_1808#` is out of this range. Search the parts of Vivado documentation about mixed-language descriptions and try to find what other VHDL types can be passed to Verilog integer parameters. If there are none I am afraid you will need to design an intermediate Verilog wrapper with two parameters, one for the 16 most significant bits and a second for the 16 least significant bits.

Comment: Well your constant is 32-bits long and your type is 48 bits long. This does not match. If the address is an IP address it is indeed 32 bits long. So use a `unsigned (31 downto 0)`. Why did you declare a 48 bits vector? If it is an Ethernet address things are different because they are 48 bits long. But then the constant shall not be `x"A9FE_1808"`. It shall be something like `x"A9FE_1808_BEEF"`.